# Override pure virtual method with parent class's implementation in C++

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, virtual-functions

I am using multiple inheritance to provide two different interfaces that share similar a method. The MWE code is as follows:

```
struct A {
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

struct B {
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

struct C : public A {
    virtual void foo() override { }
};

struct D : public B, public C {
};

int main(void) {
    D x;
    return 0;
}
```

But this produces the following error when compiling with `g++`:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:17:4: error: cannot declare variable ‘x’ to be of abstract type ‘D’
  D x;
    ^
main.cpp:13:8: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘D’:
 struct D : public B, public C {
        ^
main.cpp:6:15: note:     virtual void B::foo()
  virtual void foo() = 0;
               ^~~
```

I am trying to avoid a diamond pattern (I just want to provide two interfaces with some methods in common), and I would rather not have to reimplement `foo()` in `struct D`, even if it is just to call `C::foo()`.

Is there any way around that?

Comment: The short answer is "No". Is that all you are looking for?

Comment: Can't you just inherit `C` from both `A` and `B`, and `D` just from `C`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat In this simple example yes. But in my actual use case, interface `B` has another pure virtual method `virtual void bar() = 0;` that is not part of interface `A`, and is only implemented in `D` (but not in `C` -- `C` should only offer interface `A`). Also, `C` is a concrete (i.e. non-abstract) class that I can (and want to) instantiate. Maybe there are more complex diagrams that would allow me to do that though.

@RSahu Pretty much, but I was hoping I'd have missed some obscure tricks to achieve that.

Comment: Avoid multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to actually implement B::foo at some point, even if it just forwards to some other function, there is no way around this requirement. B::foo simply doesn't have anything to do with A::foo, they are completely different functions to the compiler.

If B::foo() really should be A::foo() it seems likely that B should derive from A and B should not have foo at all.

Comment: I would like to avoid having `B` derive from `A`, since it would create some kind of diamonds pattern (`C` and `D` both derive from `A`, but `D` also derive from `B`, which would then derive from `A` ...).